# How to achive such a Popup in android

Tags: android, menu, popup

[image: This is how the Amazon app implements it's filter in android, can someone please tell me how to implement this, I have tried PopupMenu, Fragment and some other things but not at all able to achieve any thing like this]

Can someone tell me how to implement this in an android app. If you can share code, some reference, or a tutorial. Anything will be helpful

Comment: A popup window anchored with a view!

Comment: https://github.com/shehabic/Droppy

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar I am looking for something different here, I am able to do the way they have done but I want each element of the list to behave as a spinner

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Dialog` that would show when you click at filter_box.
Just create class `MyDialog extends Dialog` and place your xml layout the place you need "popup" show.

Comment: please give me some more information, I am not able to follow

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate your custom layout to popup window.

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext(.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,400,400); 

 popupWindow.showAtLocation(attachment_button, Gravity.CENTER, 10, 200);
```

Take custom listview in your layout.